# Is this possible to deploy a ListView related to Queue?

Tags: list-view, queue

[Here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000haMyAAI) and [here](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2014/03/salesforce-list-view-not-visible-in.html) it is suggested that it is not possible to deploy or migrate List View which is Queue-related.

Is there any official documentation link which clearly states this that in the current Winter 18 release there is no possibility to deploy a List View related to a Queue?

Are there any common workarounds to this?

Comment: I found this in their known issues:
Some customers may have observed that they are unable to add List Views to Outbound Change Sets if the List View Contains any value(other than --None--) in the Queue dropdown under Filter By Owner section.



The site does list a workaround, however I don't think it's a *great* one.
Workaround
Select "--None--" in the Queue dropdown under Filter By Owner section 


https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000001AHTAA2

Comment: @JenJohnson interesting